# Создание бекапа pg_probackup-15

Tags: linux, postgresql, резервное-копирование

Проблема следующая.

Пытаюсь создать бекап Postgres-15 утилитой pg_probackup-15.
Бекап должен сложиться в этот каталог: /mnt/backup/*my_host_name*/backups/main/

При запуске команды:

```
pg_probackup-15 backup -B /mnt/backup/pvm-rak-pg-01/ --instance main -b FULL --stream --compress --delete-wal –expired
```

получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: Cannot change mode of "/mnt/backup/*my_host_name*/backups/main/RTO9GI/backup.control.tmp": Operation not permitted
```

Права на каталог 777, владелец root root.
chown владельца не меняет.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, где я накосячил. OC Ubuntu 20.04.6.

Comment: На всякий случай — а файловая система в /mnt/backup какая?

Comment: Файловая система - btrfs   она же synology

Comment: а подключенна как?

Comment: В fstab прописаны вот такие параметры:   /dev/mapper/ubuntu1804--template--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu1804--template--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
//pck-nas-01/PG /mnt/backup cifs rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/etc/cifs.credentials 0 0

Comment: `cifs` — это, мягко говоря, не очень похоже на btrfs...

Comment: Самое интересное, что WAL'ы туда заходят без проблем. Но вот именно бекап создаваться не хочет